# How do I make my UsersController work nicely with current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Users can view and edit account information in my app using `UsersController`

This controller only ever shows information about the current user.

I want to adjust the routes so that:

- `get /account` accesses `UsersController#show`, user_id is retrieved from a `current_user` variable
- `get /account/edit` similarly accesses `UsersController#edit`
- `put /account/` will hit `UsersController#update`, again using `current_user` instead of an ID

Basically I want to refer to UsersController as 'account' in my URLs and I don't want to use IDs because I'm always just using the current user. I also don't want URLs like /users/1 to function at all.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are talking about singular resources.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

```
# Not sure if you need this
resource :users, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]    

# This is what you are looking for
resource :user, :as => :account, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
```

### Update

Since you need "/account" instead of "/user", you should do

```
resource :account, :controller => :users, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Comment: It seems that `:as => :account` makes the route helpers use the word 'account' such as `edit_account_path`, but the URLs are still in the form `/user`

Comment: (but this definitely does cleanly fix my ID issue)

Answer (score 0):

Given your setup, you probably have something like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users
```

You should be able to just change it to this:

```
resources :users, :as => "account"
```

I haven't tested it but this should work. For more info, check the [Rails guides on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't address the issue of removing IDs from the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

1. In your route.rb:

   > resources :users, :as=>'accounts'
2. In your route.rb, remove resources :users and add:

   > match '/account'=>'users#show'
   >   match '/account/edit'=>'users#edit'
   >   match '/account/'=>'users#update'